# Is the gauge big enough? String Pixel

Tags: power, led, dc, led-matrix, pixels

I think I might need different pixels or an additional power supply.

I bought 10 strings of 50 (12mm, 12v) pixels (aka WS2811 12mm 12V LED)  to do my first matrix project.  It says that is uses 22awg wire.  I am planning on doing a 21 pixel x 16 pixel display which will be a total of 336 pixels.  The power supply is a 12VDC/350 Watts.

I am worried that the wiring in the strings is not a high enough gauge.

Using the RGB Pixel Light Power Calculator (http://spikerlights.com/calcpower.aspx) it shows an amp load of 16.8.  I was planning on doing power injection every 100 pixels to keep the volatge drop low across the entire run.
I am worried that this load is to much for the 22awg wire.

Will this be okay to run on a single string?  Also I am using the Picap as the controller.  If so, what size wire should I be running power to the strings.

Edit:
Link to LEDs ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B071R5HKDR/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071R5HKDR))

Comment: Do your really mean pixels or might you mean LEDs?

Comment: Sorry the community I have been looking at calls them pixels. They are WS2811 12mm 12V LEDs

Comment: 16.8 Amps is too much for 22awg wire. But I don't know how your circuit is arranged.

Comment: It is a single stand of 336 LEDs.  Every 100 of those light will be a spliced line from the power supply injecting power to not allow for voltage drop.

Comment: Love it when people introduce new lingo to engineers and we try to negotiate with them what it really means!  How about a link to the string of LED lights?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I added a link to to the post.  I wonder if I should split it into 2 separate runs.  The calculator says 168 LEDs would only be a 8.4A draw.

Comment: You better run the power to each line or row by separate pair of wires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From link:

> Quantity: 50 LEDs /string, 10 strings in total;
> Operating voltage: DC 12V;
> Power: 0.6W/LED

$$50 LED's \times 0.6W/LED = 30W / string$$

$$I = \frac {30W} {12V} = 2.5A/string$$

10 strings = 25A or 300W.  So 12V/350W power supply is fine.

30W / string assumes all LEDs are ON and each is drawing 0.6W.

So #22 AWG should be able to handle a single strand of 50 LEDs at 2.5A DC.  The actual capabilities means the shorter the wire to the power supply the better.  No extension cord between power supply and string.

But not connected in series.  All of the strings must be connected to the power supply separately or in parallel.  5A (two strings in series) would be too much for #22 AWG.

---

*V+ to V+, V- to V-, data to data*.  That's parallel.

The problem comes when you make statements like *injecting power every 100*.  That's series and that will fail.

Power 1, String 1, Power 2?, String 2, Power 3?.  No idea how that will even work.

You also have to factor in distance.  Longer from Power Supply, the greater the voltage drop to the wire.

So parallel.  All strings of LEDs leave the power supply, all V+ are connected together, all V-.

Data may be a problem.  If you connect all data, you may be controlling all LED 1 in every string.  All LEDs 2, etc.  So your data should probably be separate.

If you want to drive strings separately, separate 35W, 12V power supplys would allow each string to be powered.  65W, 12V drives two strings.

Comment: Since they are all wired directly to the next led with the same wires (V+ to V+, V- to V-, data to data), that would be parallel wiring correct?  also that means I could just wire them all in one long strand with injecting power every 100 to avoid voltage drop?

Comment: That's parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently building a 95 x 47 pixel matrix panel, 1" pitch that is  4' x 8' in size. I'm using 4456 pixels comprised of 44 strings of 100 and a string of 56. First - terminology. No, we can't and should not refer to these devices just as "LEDS" as that implies they are single element devices. They are not - they're three LEDs (red, green, blue) packaged together in a single 8mm casing. The generic term "pixel" is appropriate to represent their functionality, which is to allow three LEDs to color-mix the same way pixels behave in a LCD panel, but these specific 8mm devices are referred to by the holiday lighting community as "nodes", or sometimes "bullets" (https://www.holidaycoro.com/12mm-Pixel-Node-12v-EasyPlug3-xConnect-p/711-wp.htm), which differentiates them from other LED pixels that have a different form factor, such as strips (https://www.holidaycoro.com/30-10-Pixel-Strip-2-Meters-EasyPlug3-xConnect-p/757-wp.htm). The generic term "pixel" also has significance in doing the DMX math. We all understand a pixel requires 3 DMX control channels, and a DMX universe is defined as 512 channels. Since a pixel needs 3 channels, a DMX universe is sufficient for 170 pixels (510/3), and we ignore the last two channels in the universe. Now for the power issue. I've previously built smaller panels (36 x 48 @ 2" spacing, and power injected every 96 pixels, which worked fine. The topology for the power injection is 2 500W power supplies. Two 16 AWG 2 conductor cables emanate from each PS, one cable feeds 4 18 AWG jumpers, the other 5, connected to the V+ at the beginning of each string. The strings of WS2811 I bought (from Ray Wu in China) have extra V+ and gnd wires coming out of the 3 pin connector (V+, Data and gnd) for the purpose of power injection. The controller (SanDevices 1804) is separately powered, so only Data and gnd are sent from it to the 4 connected strands (432, 480, 432, 480 pixels ea). The power injection is therefore fed in parallel to the series connected groupings at even 96 pixel intervals. So, the four 12V lines are designed to carry 288, 230, 288, 230 watts each, broken down by the jumpers to 57.6 watts each line. 57.6 x 18 = 1,036.8 watts. A little over the 1,000 watt capacity of the the 2 PS's but the rule of thumb for pixels is that they should not ever be driven to more than 80% if you turn them all on to full white, which in practice should never happen. And FWIW, old server power supplies work great for this application. I have 2 500W and a 1,000W supply I picked up at a electronics surplus for $10 each. They show up on ebay with similar pricing.